# Cannot set the default min and max values for ionic ion-range

Tags: ionic-framework, slider, ionic5, ion-range-slider

I am trying to use the `ion-range` from ionic **v5** (latest) here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/range

Their demo shows the ability to set a default min and max values when I have 2 knobs slider.

The documentation says to use `number | { lower: number; upper: number; }` to set the value, however, the range part doesn't work.

Here's the code I use:

```
<ion-range dualKnobs="true" min="1" max="7" step="1" snaps="true" pin="true" value="{ lower: 2; upper: 3; }">
  <ion-label slot="start">1</ion-label>
  <ion-label slot="end">7</ion-label>
</ion-range>
```

And here's the output (I'm using an `rtl` settings)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out: I need to pass a `JSON` object to value property like this:

`[value]="{ lower: '2', upper: '3'}`